# java sort the names with respect to location in desc

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting

get n names and location from user and sort the names with respect to the location in descending

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String name[] = new String[5];
        String location[] = new String[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("enter the name");
            name[i] = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println("enter the  location");
            location[i] = sc.nextLine();
        }

        Arrays.sort(location, Collections.reverseOrder()); //desc
        System.out.println("Name and location:");
        System.out.println(name[0] + " " + location[0]);
        System.out.println(name[1] + " " + location[1]);
        System.out.println(name[2] + " " + location[2]);
        System.out.println(name[3] + " " + location[3]);
        System.out.println(name[4] + " " + location[4]);  /*here the names are not changed but the locations are comes with sorted order so the names and locations are mis matched. could you please help me?*/
    }
}
```

Comment: You've only given us a problem statement and not a question.

Comment: Java is an object oriented language, and so it would be much easier to sort a collection or array of objects, rather than two separate arrays.  Is there any chance you could get the names and locations into a single class?

Comment: you should use a TreeMap with key as location and name as value..It will ensure your data is sorted by location. You can then simply iterate over the TreeMap keys (location)and fetch the value (name)

Comment: question is there inside the bottom of the code "michael".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You store name and location in two different arrays. Then you only reverse the order of the array containing the location. The quickest fix is to also reverse the order of the array containing the names:

```
Arrays.sort(name, Collections.reverseOrder()); // desc name too
```

But in generall, it is bad practice to store information in two different arrays and "matching" it by trusting the arrays are ordered identically. You might want to consider using a [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) instead or building a custom object where you store name and location and than put that object into an array or List.

Comment: i want sort only the locations but in the final answer names and locations should match.

Comment: Do you want the locations to be _sorted_ by a specific criteria, i.e. alphabetically? At the moment you only reverse them.

Answer (score 0):

Your locations array is getting sorted, Your names array will display as it is since both of these arrays are not connected, if you want the name to be mapped with the location there are two ways to achieve it.

Method 1 :
Create a class name Info and make a Array of objects of that class:

```
class Info{
   String name, location;
}
```

Create a ArrayList of object:

```
ArrayList<Info> info = new ArrayList<>();
```

Sort this list based on location than.

Method 2:Simply create a TreeMap and store location as key and name as its value.

```
TreeMap<String, String> info = new TreeMap<>();
info.put("location","name");
```

> Note: If using TreeMap than ensure that all your locations are unique. Since key should be unique.